# What requirements should be added in buildozer if we've used firebase-admin in Python?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm working on Python kivy which uses firebase-admin, requests, cryptography modules. So if I directly mention this modules in buildozer requirements, it is not working on my android device(closing immediately). So, Please tell me what requirements are to be added in buildozer requirements.

Comment: Can you provide the snapshot of your `buildozer.spec` file, to get more insight

Comment: Always run logcat with your packaging to see what exactly goes wrong. A lot of the times, big libraries and modules come with a lot of dependencies themselves which have to be required as well. Go to their website or github repo or check their setup.py file to see what modules need. Also sometimes beyond this you may have to package a cli app if the module is a wrapper like ffpyplyer, for this you have to specify a p4a recipe. If kivy themselves have already defined a recipe for the library you could use it but if not you are going to have to create your own

Comment: @OmidKetabollahi I'm using Google colab for converting to apk. So, I can't use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mention these dependencies in the requirements

`requirements = python3,kivy, firebase-admin, cachecontrol, msgpack, requests, certifi, charset-normalizer, idna, urllib3, google-api-core, google-auth, cachetools, pyasn1-modules, pyasn1, rsa, pyasn1, googleapis-common-protos, protobuf, google-api-python-client, google-auth-httplib2, httplib2, pyparsing, uritemplate, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-core, proto-plus, google-cloud-storage, google-resumable-media, google-crc32c` 
Then it works well